# Appending parameter to the table name removes the dot operator

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have given a parameter to my sql script which i use to create new tables.
`CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE1&1`.

Now when i'm trying to perform an operation on the table using the parameter the dot operator is not showing.

I'm running a script form which i'm calling the sql script. I'm using a unix server.

this is the operation I'm trying to perform
`select * from TMP_TABLE1&1 where TMP_TABLE1&1.LISTING_STATUS='N'`
but after running the script with parameter as `test1` it removes the '.' from the query and when I check the error log the log shows the query as
`select * from TMP_TABLE1&1 where TMP_TABLE1test1LISTING_STATUS='N'`

why is the dot operator going away? Is there a way around this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [double dot](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#2_8) (`..`). Otherwise it is like concatenation operator in this context.

```
TMP_TABLE1&1..LISTING_STATUS='N'
```

Default [`CONCAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-9DDF30FF-F997-45F2-9550-7C8BA9AB14B3) operator in sqlplus is `.`

Comment: A period terminates a substitution variable in SQL\*Plus. It's not a concatenation operator.